# Dependency injection in unit testing, xUnit

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, xunit

This might be a stupid question, but I'm having one of those days.

I have a class called `JwtManager` and an interface called `IJwtManager`, I'm trying to inject the interface into a unit-testing class so I can test it but it doesn't work, the compiler gives me this message: `The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data: IJwtManager jwtManager`.

I think the problem is the compiler doesn't know what class should the interface be mapped to, but how can I write the equivalent of `services.AddScoped<>()` in a test class?

Code sample of test class:

```
public class JwtManagerTests
{
    private readonly IJwtManager jwtManager;
    public JwtManagerTests(IJwtManager jwtManager)
    {
        this.jwtManager = jwtManager;
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Test_Something()
    {
        // Test here
    }
}
```

Comment: What DI container are you using?

Comment: Why are you using a DI container at all? What exactly are you trying to test? The JwtManager? Some other class? If you're trying to test a concrete class called JwtManager, then why are you bothering with an IJwtManager interface? Just do `var jwtManager = new JwtManager();` and then invoke whatever functionality you need to on it for your test.

Comment: If you are using .NET Core (including .NET 5 or 6), you can build your own service host.  Scroll to the Console App example near the bottom of: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-6.0 for an example.

Comment: @Flydog57 Why? Why would someone need to build a service host just for a test? And even if they did, how does that help answer this question?

Comment: @mason because the constructor's parameters won't be empty all the time, for example, I inject `IConfiguration` into the `JwtManager`, and for other services, I inject a lot of other interfaces like `IUnitOfWork`, `IHttpContextAccessor`, etc. That's why I was looking for dependency injection instead of doing some manual work for each service I wanna test.

Comment: @Flydog57 I use .NET 6

Comment: Okay, but each test is likely going to use a different implementation of that dependency, because each test needs different inputs and outputs. For a unit test, an IOC container really isn't useful and is just going to unnecessarily couple your tests, and make it hard to support new scenarios without breaking unrelated existing tests. Instead, just declare an instance of the class you want to test. If it has dependencies, either mock them or construct purpose built ones.

Comment: For example, [this creates an IConfiguration with some settings](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ksz09X), that can then be passed to the JwtManager.

Comment: @mason thank you so much! actually I've followed your advice and I'm trying to mock the configurations right now by doing the following:

`configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("JwtSecrets.json");`

`configuration = configurationBuilder.Build();`
but I've stumbled upon another problem, the `.AddJsonFile()` looks into the /bin/debug and I want it to look in another directory, so, currently, I'm in the rabbit hole :D
anyways, thank you man for the advice, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Don't make your test depend on outside resources like a JSON file. Keep it all self contained if you can. Similar to the link I sent where I built an IConfiguration using an in memory provider.

Comment: @mason in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-6.0) the only way mentioned for having a JSON section is to import it as a `.JSON` file, do you I tried to do as your snippet says, but I can't make a section like this

`{ 
section: {

"key": "value",

"key2": "value"
}
}`

Comment: Okay, so you have your values in a section. That's supported with in memory collection as well, using a section:key syntax. See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ln0ZDY).

Comment: Awesome. I had to learn how to do that just so I could answer you, as generally we don't depend directly on IConfiguration, but rather on some strongly typed configuration class.  So we both learned something. I'll post an answer soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a DI container with a unit test project is possible, but really overkill. It forces you to share dependencies between tests, which makes adjusting a dependency's behavior to suit a particular test more difficult, as you end up breaking other tests.

Instead, we should strive to define the dependencies of our system under test right there in our test method. You mentioned that your JwtManager class has a dependency on IConfiguration. No problem.

```cs
[Fact]
public void JwtManagerShouldCreateJwtWhenDetailsAreValid()
{
    // Arrange
    var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddInMemoryCollection(
    new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "section:key1", "value1" },
        { "section:key2", "value2"}
    }).Build();

    var jwtManager = new JwtManager(configuration);

    // Act
    var result = jwtManager.CreateJwt("some input");

    // Assert
    result.Should().BeAValidJwt();
}
```

One nice thing about this is you don't have to add any configuration to your configuration object except exactly what the test needs. And if a different test of JwtManager needs different configuration settings to test a different scenario, that's easily doable now, since the configuration isn't coming from one single IoC container.

I'd caution against directly depending on IConfiguration in your classes though. It's generally better to depend on a strongly typed class instead. It makes the dependencies a lot clearer (you don't have to open up JwtManager to see what settings it would have used from IConfiguration) and the syntax is cleaner in the tests. For example:

```cs
public class JwtManagerSettings
{
    public string SomeSetting { get; set; }

    public int SomeOtherSetting { get; set; }
}

public class JwtManager
{
    readonly JwtManagerSettings _settings;

    public JwtManager(JwtManagerSettings settings)
    {
        _settings = settings;
    }
}

[Fact]
public void JwtManagerShouldCreateJwtWhenDetailsAreValid()
{
    // Arrange
    var settings = new JwtManagerSettings
    {
        SomeSetting = "abc",
        SomeOtherSettings = 123
    };

    var jwtManager = new JwtManager(settings);

    // Act
    var result = jwtManager.CreateJwt("some input");

    // Assert
    result.Should().BeAValidJwt();
}
```

In your actual app, Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration is fully capable of resolving a complex type like JwtManagerSettings from an IConfiguration. Wherever you configure your IoC container (such as Startup.cs) you can do this:

```cs
//assuming your settings are defined in a JSON key called "JwtManager"
var jwtManagerSettings = configuration.Get<JwtManagerSettings>("JwtManager");
services.AddSingleton(jwtManagerSettings);
```

```json
{
    "JwtManager": {
        "SomeSetting": "abc",
        "SomeOtherSetting": 123
    }
}
```